# WinUI 3 Modify application's MainWindow Title from the Settings page in a NavigationView

Tags: c#, desktop-application, code-behind, winui-3, mainwindow

I have a winui 3 desktop application running on Windows 10.  In the setting page of the navigationview I want to allow the user to change environments and have the environment indicated in the MainWindow's Title.

On the MainWindow's code behind I initially set the title:

```
namespace MetricReporting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty window that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Title = $"EMB Metric Reporting Tool {getSelectedEnvironment()}";
            MasterContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(pageHome));
            MasterNavigation.Header = "Home";
            // Retrieve the window handle (HWND) of the current WinUI 3 window.
            var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
            // For EPPlus spreadsheet library for .NET         
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        }

        private string getSelectedEnvironment()
        {
            return " (Non-Production)";
        }
```

In my button click method on my 'Settings' page, I do not know how to reference the MainWindow's Title:

```
private void envProd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayEnvProddDialog();
    MainWindow.Title = $"EMB Metric Reporting Tool  (Production)";
}
```

The above code gets a syntax error of
cs0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Window.Title'

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: The Settings page needs to access the instance of Window by means of [Frame.Navigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-xaml-controls-frame-navigate(windows-ui-xaml-interop-typename-system-object)), static fields or [something else](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/cbfc1fbee1aa4450e3e1fc5294f1d2a6717570b4/WinUIGallery/Helper/WindowHelper.cs#L55). Have you solved your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `MainWindow` accessible:

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static MainWindow MainWindow { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        MainWindow.Activate();
    }
}
```

then in your `SettingsPage`:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.MainWindow.Title = "Your new title.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and quick reply.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?